# PHP Application Syncing DBs not working after ldap updated to 2.4.47

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb, openldap

After my Debian Server did the following updates:

```
(Reading database ... 118558 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libldap2-dev_2.4.47+dfsg-3+deb10u5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libldap2-dev:amd64 (2.4.47+dfsg-3+deb10u5) over (2.4.47+dfsg-3+deb10u4) ...
Preparing to unpack .../ldap-utils_2.4.47+dfsg-3+deb10u5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking ldap-utils (2.4.47+dfsg-3+deb10u5) over (2.4.47+dfsg-3+deb10u4) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libldap-2.4-2_2.4.47+dfsg-3+deb10u5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libldap-2.4-2:amd64 (2.4.47+dfsg-3+deb10u5) over (2.4.47+dfsg-3+deb10u4) ...
Setting up libldap-2.4-2:amd64 (2.4.47+dfsg-3+deb10u5) ...
Setting up ldap-utils (2.4.47+dfsg-3+deb10u5) ...
Setting up libldap2-dev:amd64 (2.4.47+dfsg-3+deb10u5) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.5-2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.28-10) ...
```

my application that syncs data from two mariadb databases stopped working properly. It can read data but seems not writing.
The file that connects to SQL: https://pastebin.com/w9pxevnL

I get no error at the logs. Any idea?

Comment: Try turning on mysqli error reporting with something like `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` (or `MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL`, the one you pick can affect whether it counts as a fatal error or not)

Comment: with strict there is no error. with all main page doesn't load and show the following Fatal error that seems it's general warning that has nothing to do with my problem?: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: No index used in query/prepared statement SELECT product_id FROM mpw_product in /var/www/***/html/scripts/product-sync/DB.php:128 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/***/html/scripts/product-sync/DB.php(128): mysqli->query('SELECT `product...') #1 /var/www/***/html/scripts/product-sync/index.php(31): DB2->getExistingProducts() #2 {main} thrown in /var/www/***/html/scripts/product-sync/DB.php on line 128